# print one two three in sequence from three different threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

I am working on below interview question:

> There are three threads in a process. The first thread prints 1 1 1
>   ..., the second one prints 2 2 2 ..., and the third one prints 3 3 3
>   ... endlessly. How do you schedule these three threads in order to
>   print 1 2 3 1 2 3 ...

I came up with below code which prints `1 2 1 2 1 2` using two threads but I am not able to figure out the condition on how to print number `3` here from third thread.

```
public class PrintOneTwoThree {
  private static boolean isFirst = true;
  private static final Object lock = new Object();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // first thread
    new Thread(() -> {
      try {
        synchronized (lock) {
          for (;;) {
            while (!isFirst) {
              lock.wait();
            }
            System.out.print("1 ");
            isFirst = false;
            lock.notify();
          }
        }
      } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
      }
    }).start();

    // second thread
    new Thread(() -> {
      try {
        synchronized (lock) {
          for (;;) {
            while (isFirst) {
              lock.wait();
            }
            System.out.print("2 ");
            isFirst = true;
            lock.notify();
          }
        }
      } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
      }
    }).start();
  }
}
```

How to solve this kind of problem efficiently?

Comment: *How to solve this kind of problem efficiently?* **Don't** use threads for sequential activities.

Comment: Yes that's true but since this is some interview question so I am trying to work on that.

Comment: If you need three tasks to be performed in order, the only sane thing to do is use one thread.  Anything else is going to be inefficient and ugly. BTW `System.out.println` is single threaded so matter how many threads you use only one thread can be in this method at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a general working example using a counter to give permission to one thread at a time for `n` threads:

```
public class PrintOneTwoThree {
    private static int currentTask;
    private static int totalThreads;
    private static final Object lock = new Object();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        currentTask = 0;
        totalThreads = 3;

        for (int i = 0; i < totalThreads; i++) {
            createThread(i);
        }
    }

    static void createThread(int id) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                for (;;) {
                    synchronized (lock) {
                        while (currentTask != id) {
                            lock.wait();
                        }

                        System.out.print(id + 1 + " ");
                        currentTask = (currentTask + 1) % totalThreads;
                        lock.notifyAll();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 ...
```

[Try it!](https://repl.it/repls/ClassicCraftySets)

A couple remarks:

- `notify()` works fine for the 2-thread version (because there is a maximum of one other thread blocking on the variable), but will deadlock in a 3+ version if a thread exits the critical section and `notify`s that the condition variable `currentTask` is available but the wrong thread wins the race to obtain the lock. I'm not sure if `notifyAll()` is appropriate design here, because there is only one thread that can make progress, so it seems like a stand in for re-checking the condition predicate and using `notify()`.
- I moved the `for (;;)` outside of the synchronized section to keep the thread-safe scope as narrow is possible. This example is contrived because if you wanted this exact behavior of accessing a single resource and nothing else, it doesn't make sense to add the overhead of threading--you may as well do it deterministically in a single thread. In a real-world example, threads would perform thread-safe work elsewhere in the `for (;;)` loop when they're not blocking on the condition variable, so it seems logical to design with that in mind.

Comment: can you add some explanation on how this is working so that I can understand better?

Comment: Sure. I'm more familiar with multithreading in non-Java languages, so let me know if my information is incorrect or the explanation is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of boolean flag use integer counter and check remainder when divided by 3 and increment counter after each print.
And since there will be several threads waiting on the same lock it is better to use `notifyAll`.

```
private static int counter = 0;

new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            synchronized (lock) {
                for (;;) {
                    while (counter % 3 != 0) {
                        lock.wait();
                    }
                    System.out.print("1 ");
                    ++counter;
                    lock.notifyAll();
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
        }
    }).start();

//And the same stuff for other two threads just replacing value for remainder in if and value in print
```

Comment: can you provide an example so that I can understand better?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class PrintOneTwoThree {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            Printers sp = new Printers();

            ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
            executor.submit(new FirstNumberProducer(sp, 9));
            executor.submit(new SecondNumberProducer(sp , 9));
            executor.submit(new ThirdNumberProducer(sp , 9));
            executor.shutdown();
        }

    }


    class Printers {

        Semaphore first = new Semaphore(1);
        Semaphore second = new Semaphore(0);
        Semaphore third = new Semaphore(0);

        public void printFirstNumber() {
            try {
                first.acquire();
            }catch(InterruptedException exception) {

            }
            System.out.print("1");
                second.release();
        }

        public void printSecondNumber() {
            try {
                second.acquire();
            }catch(InterruptedException exception) {

            }
            System.out.print("2");
            third.release();
        }

        public void printThirdNumber() {
            try {
                third.acquire();
            }catch(InterruptedException exception) {

            }
            System.out.print("3");
            first.release();
        }

    }

    class FirstNumberProducer implements Runnable {

        Printers sp;
        int index;

        FirstNumberProducer(Printers sp , int index) {
            this.sp = sp;
            this.index = index;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(int i = 1 ; i <= index ; i = i + 3 ) {
                sp.printFirstNumber();
            }
        }
    }

    class SecondNumberProducer implements Runnable{
        Printers sp;
        int index;

        SecondNumberProducer(Printers sp , int index) {
            this.sp = sp;
            this.index = index;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(int i = 2 ; i <= index ; i = i + 3) {
                sp.printSecondNumber();
            }
        }
    }

    class ThirdNumberProducer implements Runnable{
        Printers sp;
        int index;

        ThirdNumberProducer(Printers sp , int index) {
            this.sp = sp;
            this.index = index;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(int i = 3 ; i <= index ; i = i + 3) {
                sp.printThirdNumber();
            }
        }
    }
```

***Output of the program is :***

```
 123123123
```